# Is it possible to extract data from point vectors according to the 'derived' feature ID?

Tags: qgis

I am comparing two slightly offset raster datasets (DSMs) in order to correct for both XY and Z offset. I am doing this by point sampling  data across both and checking for differences in elevation value. So far I have identified features common to both by placing a number of point vectors, one shapefile for each raster. I did this in the same order over both rasters so that the feature IDs were consistent for each identifiable feature in each DSM (i.e. a boulder found on both DSMs would have ID '1', a specific building would have ID '2', and so on). I have extracted the elevation data associated with each point, and this seems to have kept the derived feature ID, when checking using the identify tool. However, weirdly, in the attribute table, the points are not numbered/listed according to this derived feature ID, which means I am unable to easily make a comparison. Ideally, I'd like to list by derived feature ID, so I can then copy into a text file which would give me the X,Y and Z coordinates of each feture and I could make corrections accordingly.

Hope that makes sense... Are there any ideas of what I could do here?

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange. As is your question is quite hard to read. I would recommend breaking it down into paragraphs, perhaps some images would help clarify as well.

Comment: I can't understand exactly what you want to do. Seems to me that you want to copy one attribute from one layer to another or you just want to have in your attribute table the feature ID? If is the second case, you just need to use the field calculator to create a new field using the expression ```$id```.